# How do I force IE to load site with .net framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer

I have a web app then needs framework 3.5 to run.  A system update keeps installing framework 4.5, this breaks the web app.  I updated the web.config and even tried an app config for IE (config listed below).  But neither work, I downloaded processactivityview tool to see what was going on.  It seems to load framework 4.5 before reading the config file.

How can I force the IE to load this page with framework 3.5?

[image: screenshot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: When you say: `How can I force the IE to load this page with framework 3.5.` did you mean Stack Overflow's website or your website?

Comment: This question makes no sense at all. Why would IE config affect the .Net version of your web app?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to figure out the best way to phrase my question :P The site I am trying to load is an internal site at my organization that runs a web app that requires dot net framework 3.5 or less to load.

Comment: So you need to configure your *web app*, not Internet Explorer.

Comment: I don't have control of the web app it is legacy app that is no longer supported.

Comment: @man0man, how you know that the web app needs 3.5 .NET framework?  can you provide more info about the whole problem? please, update your question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "force the IE to load this page with framework 3.5." IE is on the client side and ASP.NET is on the server side; why would they have anything to do with each other? IE is loading HTML content, *not* .NET code.

Comment: What several folks are saying is that the .NET version installed on the clients should have NO EFFECT on the web app loaded in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to IIS, create new Application Pool in IIS for FW 3.5 and assign your app to it.

Comment: I don't have access to the server side, just the clients that connect to the page.  We are in the process of updating the server but that may not happen until the end of the year.